# Disable auto-resizing of uploaded images, but only for certain filename

Tags: functions, images, filters, uploads

How can I totally disable the wordpress auto-resizing when uploading images, but only for images that have a certain string in its filename.

Eg. disable auto-resizing on images in which its filenames contains the string "HD".

image_xyz.jpeg >>  auto-resizing function enabled

imageHD_xyz.jpeg >>  auto-resizing function disabled

image_HD.jpeg >>  auto-resizing function disabled

Whats the reason behind this?

I have to work whit images in the best quality on a specific plugin which will send them to another platform and will not be published in the mainsite, so therefore resized versions are not needed

The following code works but based on file format.

```
function wpdocs_disable_upload_sizes( $sizes, $image_meta ) {
 
    // Get filetype data.
    $filetype = wp_check_filetype( $image_meta['file'] );
     
    $exclude_file_types = array(
        'image/png',
    );
 
    // Check if file type is on exclude list 
    if ( in_array( $filetype['type'], $exclude_file_types ) ) {
        $sizes = array();
    }
 
    // Return sizes you want to create from image (None if image is gif.)
    return $sizes;
}   
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'wpdocs_disable_upload_sizes', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: WordPress always creates also a full size version of the image that you upload, which is basically a not-resized one. Do you mean that you want that WordPress doesn't create at all other sizes for certain images but only the full version?

Comment: What's your ultimate goal here? If you did this then you wouldn't even have a thumbnail for the media library, and you'd be downloading and displaying full sized versions of potentially dozens of images at a time.

Comment: Antonio Yes, that is what I want to achieve.

@JacobPeattie I have to work with images in the best quality on a specific plugin which will send them to another platform and will not be published in the mainsite, so therefore resized versions are not needed. Thats why I want to only make this work for images whit a certain string in its filename so I can control it.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try Below Codes:**

```
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'prefix_remove_default_images' );
function prefix_remove_default_images( $sizes ) {
if (preg_match('/(hd)/', get_attached_file( $attachment_id )) {
 unset( $sizes['small']); // 150px
 unset( $sizes['medium']); // 300px
 unset( $sizes['large']); // 1024px
 unset( $sizes['medium_large']); // 768px
 return $sizes;
}
}
```

And You can use **[Stop Generating Unnecessary Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-sizes/)** WordPress Plugin to disable for all images size very easily.

Comment: Ive tried the code using code snippets, but I get the following error: "The code snippet you are trying to save produced a fatal error on line 0:".

What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

this one works with me based on your code snippet of excluding a file type from cropping:

```
function wpdocs_disable_hd_image_from_auto_resize( $sizes, $image_meta ) {
 
   // Check if file name contains hd letters
   if (preg_match('/(hd)/', $image_meta['file'])) {
        $sizes = array();
    }
 
   // Return sizes you want to create from image (None if it contains "hd" in the file name.)
    return $sizes;
}   
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'wpdocs_disable_hd_image_from_auto_resize', 10, 2 );
```